# Lightweight SQL editor for Eclipse

Tags: sql, eclipse, editor, eclipse-plugin

Is there any simple SQL editor in Eclipse? Or do I need to find a simple SQL editor plugin for Eclipse?

By simple I mean, the editor does **NOT** connect to any DB, does syntax highlighting and preferably formatting sql is a bonus.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://www.gstaff.org/colorEditor/

Comment: As the time of the creation of the question were the requests for a software not yet forbidden. The question should be set to a "historical significance only", and not closed. Thus, I voted to reopen.

Comment: Since 2019-03-14 there is standalone and very simple plugin available at eclipse marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sql-editor - it's just for editing SQL files, syntax highlighting and contains an experimental sql formatter. So exactly what was asked for.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

for reference to add sql syntax highlighting / coloring to eclipse
you can install `Data tools platform extender sdk` from "install new software", under `Database Development`

or enter site location directly
http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates

Comment: simple as it's needed :)

Comment: "Data tools platform extender sdk" contains a SQL Editor with Syntax Highlighting which works great for me. +1 Ben K

Comment: Very good! I was also looking for some simple highlighting of SQL... and the SQL Explorer just didn't work was expected (buggy and heavy to load). This just made the trick I was looking for! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By default (on Kepler, at least), this plug in opens SQL files using the SQL File Editor, which includes connection bloat.  It does also include SQL Editor, which is the lightweight version, that you can easily set as the default editor.

Comment: update site:
 http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/

Comment: It seems to be garbage. It's not clear which dialect is supported, but I have a feeling that only the very basic is part of this plug-in (plus some irrelevent features which I can't use). Also it doesn't highlight trigger or PL/SQL related keywords.

Comment: Working link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sql-development-tools

Comment: Please refer updated : http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php (Oxygen : http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/1.14.1.201712071719/repository/)

Comment: @All - http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates - This link doesn't work at all now.

Comment: Found it (finally): https://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/milestone/

Answer (score 23):

This [Eclipse SQL Editor](http://web.archive.org/web/20120104065151/http://blog.debertshaeuser.com/index.php?page=eclipse-sql-editor) seems very lightweight.  It only does syntax highlighting and provides an outline view.  As of now the author is planning to eventually add code folding and completion, but those two features are still on the todo list.

Comment: I tried both others mentioned in answers here and both were bloated, slow, and worst of all, didn't work at all for me. This one is tiny, a breeze to install, and just works. Bravo.

Comment: How do I install this plug-in? So far I have tried copying http://blog.debertshaeuser.com/uploads/com.debertshaeuser.sql.SQLEditorPlugin_1.0.0.jar to %eclipse%/dropins, %eclipse%/plugins, %eclipse%/dropins/plugins and %eclipse/dropins/SQLEditor/eclipse/plugins but SQLEditor does not show up in the list of installed plug-ins. I am using Eclipse Galileo version 20100218-1602

Comment: If you too are unable to install the plugin then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223969/unable-to-install-eclipse-plugin-eclipse-sql-editor/6239567#6239567

Comment: copy the .jar-file into the eclipse/plugin/ folder and after restarting eclipse, .sql-files are connected to this editor. (eclipse indigo)

Comment: If you're looking for auto-indentation and syntax highlighting in a light editor, this fits the bill perfectly. Many thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 10):

Use [Toad eclipse-extension](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx) (community edition), you will get almost everything you want in an SQL editor. Search for 'toad' in eclipse market place. It has very good Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL support.

Take a look at [Installation instructions and screenshots](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/w/wiki/10446.toad-extension-for-eclipse-installation.aspx).

Alternatively, there is [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) (very good in my experience and support almost all DB's) which is built on eclipse platform and available as standalone and eclipse plugin.

Comment: they no longer offer an eclipse plugin...

Answer (score 7):

The [eclipse SQLExplorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/sqleditor.php) plugin seems light enough, and comes with a basic [SQL editor](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/sqleditor.php) (but no "format" option):

alt text

---

The official [DTP DataTool Project](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/) is much complete, but have also [its own editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_Started_with_DTP):

[image: DTP Editor]

Comment: SQLExplorer is the nicest SQL plugin I have found so far, and it's pretty lightweight.  However, it only does syntax highlighting when you are connected to a DB.

Answer (score 4):

QuantumDB is also a lightweight option that I really liked.

http://quantum.sourceforge.net/

Comment: abandonware, last release is from 2011

Answer (score 3):

Just found DBeaver : http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

looks good, plenty of features, support mssql (which I need in the moment :) ... I'll give it a try ...

Comment: DBeaver is great for people wanting to have a full DB tool. But as a plugin it has some different behaviours to standard eclipse (e.g. its SQL editor does handle standard shortcuts like CTRL + SHIFT + UP different) . Also the toolbar is extreme changing when scope changes to sql parts - at least for myself it make much "noise".

So I use DBeaver standalone and use `SQL Editor` plugin (see https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sql-editor ) inside eclipse for SQL files. It's lightweight and works fine.